# ionic4 problem with data response from API

Tags: ionic4

**i have problem with data response from api the data is empty**

**this code fil servicelogin**

```
    @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  constructor( private http:HttpClient) { }

  login(body) {
  const headers=new HttpHeaders;
  headers.append('content-Type', 'application/json'),
  headers.append('api_key', '7zttgA4kFVsD2V2n0beMpzdLQRiSAKxtVEpyeW9MaEFEND0g')   
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST')
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','X-Requested-With ')
return this.http.post('https://bell.s2c.io/api/v1/Login', body,
  { headers: headers  }).pipe(res=>res)  
}}
```

**the code login.ts**

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  private formlogin : FormGroup;
  Device:any
ListDevices:any
  constructor(private servicelogin:LoginService,private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private router : Router
    )
   { 

    this.formlogin = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: ['', Validators.required],
    password: ['',Validators.required],
  });
}

  logForm(){


   this.servicelogin.login(this.formlogin.value).subscribe(data=>{

  console.log(data)

    })
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**i test with console.log(data) to see the data response but the data is empty what is the problem ?**

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57888930/1934484

Comment: @TomasVancoillie i have the error the result is empty

Comment: do you get the data in servicelogin? Maybe you don't receive any data from that endpoint...

Comment: @TomasVancoillie yes i don't receive any data in servicelog ,maybe it is probleme with CORS ?

Comment: small tip, if the name is the same as the variable you can just specify the variable, eg `{ headers }` instead of `{headers: headers}`